# Difference between two consecutive "or" separtely VS include every condition within same "or"

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I am trying to understand the conceptual difference of doing two consecutive or separately made versus to put all the conditions inside one or. I am yielding different values by doing this:

Doing the or separately :

```
g.V(1).in('linked_to', 'used_by')
 .or(has('type', 'knows'), has('type', 'like'), has('type','follows'))
 .or(hasNot('last_used'), has('last_used',gt(datetime('2021-09-07T10:04:05.000Z'))))
 .out('linked_to', 'used_by')
 .dedup()
```

vs including the or inside one same or

```
g.V(1).in('linked_to', 'used_by')
 .or(has('type', 'knows'), has('type', 'like'), has('type','follows') , hasNot('last_used'), has('last_used',gt(datetime('2021-09-07T10:04:05.000Z'))))
 .out('linked_to', 'used_by')
 .dedup()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really do not need an `or` step here for several of the tests. You can just use `within` instead and wrap the remaining steps inside an `or`. Note that `hasNot(key)` can be an expensive filter as you are testing for the non existence of something on every vertex being tested which may not be something an index helps with. For example:

```java
g.V(1).
  in('linked_to', 'used_by').
  or(has('type', within('knows', 'like', 'follows')),
     hasNot('last_used'), 
     has('last_used',gt(datetime('2021-09-07T10:04:05.000Z'))))
```

Comment: thanks :) ! but what about the condition `, hasNot('last_used'), has('last_used',gt(datetime('2021-09-07T10:04:05.000Z')` inside the or ?

Comment: I'll update the answer but all you need to do is wrap an `or` around the steps. Note that `hasNot(key)` can be an expensive filter as you are testing for the non existence of something on every vertex.